# Create Database File Permissions

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below query to create a database.

```
USE master;  
GO  
CREATE DATABASE Apps  
ON   
( NAME = App_dat,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\Appdata.mdf',  
    SIZE = 10,  
    MAXSIZE = 50,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )  
LOG ON  
( NAME = App_log,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\Applog.ldf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;  
   GO
```

The files are successfully created. However the problem i am facing here is the .MDF and .LDF files file permissions are not set properly. when i right click on .MDF/.LDF -> Properties->Security, it is showing

> "You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object".

How can i set the file security permissions in Create Database Command itself or by any other command.

this problem can be reproduced in your machine as well using the above code. Please try and let me know if any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. SQL Server sets file permissions to full control for the service account since only the database engine needs access to the files and data within.

It's not clear why you need to access the files directly. You can change permissions using Windows Explorer, `icacls` command-line tool, or `Set-Acl` in Powershell.

Comment: thanks for the reply... To add to that, my application will import the database files (web application). To import, i have to select the file .MDF for the import operation to begin. However upon selecting the .MDF file in File Dialog window, immediately i get this error message.